# How can i add a new line every nth delimiter of a string in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to add a new line, for every nth delimiter in a string.

For example i will add a new line every 3rd '|' in the string below:

```
nthelement = 3
delimiter = '|'
string = 'AB|CD|EEEE|GGg|gger342|gff534|gre343|FGS'
#splitter here
output = 'AB|CD|EEEE|\nGGg|gger342|gff534|\ngre343|FGS'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation

```py
def delimit(s, delimiter, n): 
    segments = s.split(delimiter) # splits string by delimiter
    for i, seg in enumerate(segments): 
        if i % n == 0 and i != 0: 
            segments[i] = '\n' + seg # prepend '\n' to segment
    return delimiter.join(segments) # join segments
```

Usage:

```py
delimit('AB|CD|EEEE|GGg|gger342|gff534|gre343|FGS', '|', 3)
# output: 'AB|CD|EEEE|\nGGg|gger342|gff534|\ngre343|FGS'
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a couple solutions but this is the cleanest I've come up with so far:

```py
items = string.split(delimiter)
groups = []


while items:
    first_three, items = items[:nthelement], items[nthelement:]
    groups.append(first_three)


result = "|\n".join("|".join(g) for g in groups)
```

Output:

```py
>>> result
'AB|CD|EEEE|\nGGg|gger342|gff534|\ngre343|FGS'
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated. There is no reason to separate them into groups of n then prepend `\n` and join when in reality you can just iterate and add it for every nth item. However, I see where you are coming from.

Comment: You also forgot to pop items from `items`, which would just create an infinite loop. You also forgot to increment index, so you will always be getting the first nth items.

Comment: It does work, and I realized that I didn't look carefully. I didn't pay attention to the fact that you are unpacking the remaining items into the same variable. However, it doesn't change the fact that its overly complicated.

Comment: @KennethLew Yeah, it is complicated, but it is more simple than your answer.

Comment: It's funny because at the end of the day your solution is exactly as "complicated". You're just taking a different approach. I'd even argue that your code takes longer to understand.

Comment: Well, in my opinion I think what I wrote was more concise and self-explanatory, however I guess that also boils down to self-preference and opinion